# LINQ expression to optimize syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

```
foreach (var item in mainCanvas.Children)
{
    if (item is Button)
    {
        (item as Button).Content = "this is a button";
    }                
}
```

Can I use LINQ or other feature of .NET 4 to be more concise (maybe performant)?

Comment: Please read item 3 of effective C#. How about this: `Button castedItem = null; foreach ... castedItem = item as Button; if (castedItem != null) { // do work here } } // end foreach`. That way you are cutting the use of reflection into 2, this gaining some speed-up. A LINQ query should be as performant, probably more readable.

Comment: Concise and performant are sometimes at odds.  If this is a deep inner loop, profiling indicates you have a performance problem here and the collection under consideration is an array, you can get better performance by indexing with a standard for loop.

Comment: @Dan Bryant, see Item 11 of "Effective C#" titled "Prefer foreach loops". The JIT compiler is not dumb and does not need help. This was true back in .Net 1.1, so it cannot be less true now. I would be surprised ... if `for` ever beats non-stupidly constructed `foreach` in C#.

Comment: @Hamish, I encountered a specific case where this was beneficial (specific target was .NET 3.5 for Silverlight), but the improvement was only noticeable because the inner loop was being invoked millions of times.  I definitely agree that it's best to prefer foreach and LINQ.

Comment: @Dan Bryant, do you think you could paste an example of what the code looked like? I am quite curious now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [**`Enumerable.OfType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
foreach (var button in mainCanvas.Children.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Content = "this is a button";
}
```

---

**Performance Measurements**

**Method 1**: OPs original suggestion

```
foreach (var item in mainCanvas.Children)
{
    if (item is Button)
    {
        (item as Button).Content = "this is a button";
    }                
}
```

**Method 2**: OfType

```
foreach (var button in mainCanvas.Children.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Content = "this is a button";
}
```

**Method 3**: Only cast once

```
foreach (var item in mainCanvas.Children)
{
    Button button = item as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Content = "this is a button";
    }                
}
```

**Method 4**: for loop:

```
List<object> children = mainCanvas.Children;
for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; ++i)
{
    object item = children[i];
    if (item is Button)
    {
        (item as Button).Content = "this is a button";
    }                
}
```

**Results**

```
Iterations per second

Method 1: 18539180
Method 2:  7376857
Method 3: 19280965
Method 4: 20739241
```

**Conclusion**

- The biggest improvement can be gained by using a simple `for` loop instead of `foreach`.
- It is also possible to improve performance slightly by casting only once.
- Using `OfType` is considerably slower.

But remember to optimize readability first, and only optimize performance if you have performance profiled and found that this specific code is the performance bottleneck.

Comment: Looks like a winner to me - short and fast. Doing stuff with lambdas seems like an overkill.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Buttons was for the example purpose. In application I have a graph with a huge number of curves. I select them and move...

Comment: I think performance-wise IEnumerable<T>.OfType() will do just as fine as original post. So if you want concise, there is a one-liner solution here, if performance is critical, I believe for-loop performs better than foreach and List.ForEach(), but that is marginal.

Comment: @serhio: The best way to find out which is fastest is to measure it. I've updated my answer with some measurements I've made.

Comment: @Mark, what about the 5th method - the hybrid of method 3 and 4? How much better is it to "cast once"? Also, this might be a dumb idea, but how about the 6th method - using `object` instead of `var` in ... say method 3? What if something like `IButton` is used instead of `Button` when casting? Finally, how do you measure the performance? Are the numbers consistent from run to run? With JIT, pre-emption, noise is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One line should do it

```
mainCanvas.Children.OfType<Button>.ToList().ForEach(b => b.Content = "this is a button");
```

Comment: That is always debatable, but this is just to answer the question, which was, after all, about it being concise. Everyone should take whatever flavor suits them.

Comment: Turning an iterator into a List, and then iterating over it is expensive.

Comment: That depends on the contents of .Children. If there is hundreds of items and only 3-4 buttons, this should be a good way. Can't tell here.

Comment: @hamish-grubijan: foreach should do the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: @serhio, `foreach` should operate on an `IEnumerable`, which can be a lazy collection.

Answer (score 1):

See if there is an `OfType<T>` extension.

```
foreach (var item in mainCanvas.Children.OfType<Button>()) 
{ 
    item.Content = "this is a button"; 
}
```

If not, you can use:

```
foreach (var item in mainCanvas.Children.Where(item=>item is Button).Cast<Button>()) 
{ 
    item.Content = "this is a button"; 
}
```

Comment: If there is not an OfType extension there will also not be a Where or a Cast extension. All 3 methods have existed since the first version of Enumerable class. Also Where cannot be used UIElementCollection as it not generic.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it's particularly superior, but there is something nice about this syntax:

Using LINQ and the Microsoft [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) framework,

```
mainCanvas.Children
   .OfType<Button>()
   .Do(b => b.Content = "I'm a button!")
   .Run();
```

Answer (score 1):

To only iterate over actual buttons in a collection, you can do:

```
foreach(Button button in mainCanvas.Children)
     button.Content = "this is a button";
```

As far as I understand, this is syntax sugar that gets converted into Method 4 above. But don't quote me on that. (EDIT: Method 3 I meant)